# Dealing with pc12 keystore in android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl

I want to enable ssl in android.Android application is running on servlets which are hosted in tomcat.Tomcat is secured by apache web server at front-end.I have created keystore using open ssl.keystore is in pc12 format.

i have created bks using portecle tool. I am using following code.Still ssl is not working.

Source Code:

```
    import android.content.Context;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import com.myclinicmyway.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

 public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

   public final Context context;


  public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }


  @Override protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);

  }// end of client connection


  private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {

    try {
      KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
      InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.docinbangalore);

      try {
        trusted.load(in, "docinbangalore".toCharArray());
      } finally {
        in.close();    
      }
      return new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }// end of catch

  }// end of ssl socket

}// end of class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.Following code worked for me

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
final Context context;
TrustManager easyTrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }    
};
  public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }


  private MySSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
      KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");      
      try {
         trusted.load(null, null);

      } finally {
      }

      MySSLSocketFactory sslfactory =  new MySSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        sslfactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        return sslfactory;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }

  }
  public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(truststore);

            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        }
    }
   }
```